# Running Java Applet Outside Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, applet

I have written a Java applet in Eclipse.  How do I run it outside eclipse, or an another computer that doesn't have Eclipse?  Will a runnable JAR File work on a non-local file system?

Comment: Why did you write an applet? An applet is something to run in a browser.

Comment: Are you sure you are talking about an applet (something that runs in a web browser)?

Comment: public class Calc extends Applet implements ActionListener

Comment: I wrote it as an Applet because i'm rather inexperienced and that is really the only way I know to write a program that has a frame and graphics capabilities.  Otherwise, all I end up with is JOptionPane notifications and console stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a runnable jar with a main method, you use JFrame rather than an Applet

Also, find a more current tutorial.  Think of awt as mostly deprecated (except for event handling and drawing).  You should be using swing for UI.

If you want to put it in a browser, you use a JApplet (the swing equivalent of Applet).

If you want to run a jar file via command line, use java -jar myJarFile.jar

Often you can just double-click it.

Make sure you exported as runnable jar.
If there's no main class specified in the manifest you can also do

java -cp myJarFile.jar main.MainClass

Comment: Thank you very much.  I have found a way around my problem.  I appreciate your advice.